# How can I workaround looping a cursor in Oracle PL/SQL 8i which uses a subscalar query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a PL/SQL procedure which needs to do a for loop through a cursor. I have read in the oracle forums that PL/SQL 8i doesn't support subscalar queries.

This is what I have so far :

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR C1
   IS
    SELECT texto,id_evento,clave_evento FROM gegf.eventos_omega_rima WHERE id_evento IN
        (select max(eo.id_evento)  from gegf.eventos_omega_rima eo, correctivo_rima.equipos b 
            where eo.fecha_ins_tab > sysdate - 25/24 and eo.fecha_ins_tab < sysdate - 1/24  and upper(eo.ORIGEN) = upper(b.nodo) and upper(b.red) = 'RIMA' group by eo.clave_evento);
    r_emp C1%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    OPEN C1;

    LOOP 
        FETCH c1 INTO r_emp;
        EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;        
        INSERT INTO CORRECTIVO_RIMA.T_CLOB VALUES (r_emp.TEXTO);
    END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

How could I workaround the fact that I can't use subscalar queries in the PL/SQL version I am using?

Comment: Oracle 8i? Really? That has been obsolete for over a decade now - and I'm pretty sure even that supported scalar subqueries. What exactly is your problem? What is the error you get? And why are you using a cursor loop in the first place? Most of the time such a cursor can be replaced by a much more efficient set-based solution with a single statement.

Comment: My client is a big corporation so suggesting a DB upgrade just to make my life easier is out of the question (Even though i think they should upgrade their systems). The PL/SQL version that comes with Oracle 8i lacks some of the features the DB supports, one of them is the subscalar queries. What i am trying to do is loop through the rows selected to parse a huge clob field and create a new table with that data. The huge CLOB is a txt file with data per each line, ie: Field X : Value Y. I only need to recover some of these fields.

Comment: According to Tom Kyte's article: "You can also (since Oracle8i Database Release 8.1.5, anyway) include a scalar subquery".

Comment: So what **is** the error you get? What about derived tables? `select * from (SELECT A,B,C, row_number() over (partition by c order by b desc) rn FROM T1) where rn = 1`

Comment: BTW, objects' names are not case-sensitive, so I cannot distinguish between t1 and T1.

Comment: @Neria Nachum  Thanks for the tips

Comment: So back to your questions: as I mentioned before, this query should be valid in Oracle 8i. Then, what exactly is the problem? Do you get an error, or it just returns wrong records? if it's the second case, try to give a different alias to the table T1.

Comment: I find the terminology confusing.  I don't know what a subscalar query is.  And your code does not contain a scalar subquery.  A scalar subquery returns one column in zero or one rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right now i am getting:                                      ORA-06550: linea 4, columna 5:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el simbolo "SELECT texto,id_evento,clave_evento FROM gegf.eventos" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:

   ( select

Comment: PLS-00103 indicates a different problem. Please edit your question and put the **real** code that generates that error into it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Sorry if im confusing people with my terms, i picked them up from my google searches in the hopes of giving a name to my issue. Im a noobish sql dev sorry. The subscalar querie would be nesting queries i think.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Done.

Comment: Did the SQL for a cursor really need to be in single quotes in 8i? It sure wasn't that way in 9i

Comment: If I recall, Oracle 8i only supported subqueries in the `from` and `select` clauses.  So, rewrite the query as a join.  I would do it as an answer, but I abhor commas in the `from` clause and Oracle 8i doesn't support modern explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, but apparently i needed to do that to be able to nest queries in this version. I ran it without them to get the next error : Error at line 1
ORA-06550: linea 6, columna 49:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el simbolo "AND" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:
   ( - + mod null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> avg
   count current max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute
   forall time timestamp interval date

Comment: <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string>
El simbolo "null" ha sido sustituido por "AND" para continuar.

Comment: How could i do a join if i have a group by clause in the nested select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PLS-00103 is telling you where the problem is; line 6 column 49. In this part of your query:

```
where eo.fecha_ins_tab > sysdate -  and
```

... something is missing after the minus sign; presumably you're trying to subtract some number of days from today, but you haven't supplied that number.

I don't have an 8i database lying around any more (perhaps not surprisingly) but I don't recall ever needing to quote a cursor query; and if you do I'm pretty sure the semicolon would need to be outside the closing quote. But that was also what was causing the earlier line 4, column 5 error, which was pointing at that opening quote.

You will also try to insert the last value twice; you need to test `C1%NOTFOUND` before the `INSERT`, immediately after the `FETCH` (unless you are using bulk collect). Of course you're inserting a dummy value, but you'll get one too many rows; with your real CLOB you'd process the last fetch value twice.

Comment: Thanks Alex, you have been very helpful. I edited the post with the latest version of my code. The PL/SQL is completing its execution but it is not inserting any rows, while the query the cursor is based on returns. Any clue as to why that might be happening?

Comment: You're sure the query on its own finds rows in the same session, and you're committing any inserted data? Or at least are not rolling it back before looking for it. You can use `dbms_output` to debug whether it's finding data and how many times it loops.

Comment: Yes i am executing the same query.My understanding is that the slash / acts as a commit, is this correct? Shouldn't i be able to query non committed data throughout the current session? I added DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Loop'); under the insert and TOAD's DBMS output window doesn't show anything even though the output is ON.

Comment: A slash does not commit. A slash executes the current SQL buffer. If you query in the same session you'll see uncommitted changes anyway, but other sessions will not unless the data is committed. But a debug before and after the loop too to make sure that's working. Seems it isn't finding any data in the query though.

Comment: Cheers man, its fixed. It appears i don't even need to use a cursor afterall haha. I learnt a lot still, i will get it right next time =) The the problem was i wasn't commiting the data. I thought it wasn't necessary to commit in order to be able to query the data in your own session and that slash took care of that.